# Opening a map and marking my waypoints

Tags: dictionary, drone.io

Does anyone know how to open up a google map and pinpoint the location of my drone on the map in real time? I'm using Python. The program needs to update every 3 sec. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FlytOS Navigation API](http://api.flytbase.com/#global-position-setpoint) to query the current location of the drone and place the coordinate on Google Map. This way you'll be able to see the real-time position of the drone. Let me know if you need further help.